# Can we possible to solve the LPN problem using Arora-Ge algorithm?

Tags: cryptanalysis, lwe

I recently studied how to solve the LWE (learning with errors) using algebraic relations proposed by Arora and Ge (paper : New Algorithms for Learning in Presence of Errors).
As I understood, for LWE instances of the form $\vec{a}_i,b_i = <\vec{a}_i,\vec{s}>+e_i~mod~q$ for some integer $q$, adversaries generate algebraic polynomials which has a root $e_i = b_i - <\vec{a}_i,\vec{s}>~mod~q$. If adversaries obtain sufficiently many polynomials, then they can recover the secret vector $\vec{s}$ using linearization technique.

Thus, I think that the Arora-Ge algorithm is also possible to solve LPN (learning parity with noise) problem since the instances are of the form $\vec{a}_i,b_i = <\vec{a}_i,\vec{s}>+e_i~mod~2$.
However, I cannot find any references about the result, so I guess that I have some mistakes.

Why can't I use Arora-Ge algorithm to solve the LPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is natural to wonder if Arora-Ge can break LPN, but as you suspect, it does not work. The essential problem is that, because the modulus is $q=2$, the method does not find the unique solution $s$, nor does it even narrow down the set of possible solutions.

The reason is that the first step of the algorithm converts each LPN sample into a quadratic (in $s$) equation that encodes the condition $\langle a_i, s \rangle = b_i \text{ or } b_i +1 \pmod{2}$. It then linearizes these equations and solves for $s$. However, observe that *any* $s’$ is a solution to these equations, because the right-hand side is always “0 or 1.” So, the system set up by the algorithm does not carry any information about $s$, from the very start.

Arora-Ge works for LWE because/when the modulus $q$ is larger than the number of possible error values. Then, the condition “$\langle a_i, s \rangle = b_i \text{ or } b_i+1 \text{ or } b_i-1 \ldots$” captures a nontrivial constraint on the secret $s$, and enough such equations can uniquely specify it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fully understood what the problem is.

Comment: oh, I have one more question. When we want to solve LWE problem using Arora-Ge algorithm, we easily generate new LWE samples by adding for small random error. (We can immediately generate new LWE samples from given LWE samplers.) Why we cannot use Arora-Ge algorithm in this case? Since we add small error, the modulus $q$ is still larger than the number of possible errors as you said, so we easily obtain $m(>n^2)$ LWE samples with a dimension $n$ that is a constraint of Arora-Ge algorithm.

Comment: When you create new samples by combining existing ones, the size of the resulting error is larger. Arora-Ge needs roughly $n^d$ samples, where $d$ is the number of possible values of the error. So, it’s not clear that there’s any benefit from using this technique, though I haven’t worked out the tradeoff carefully.

Comment: Sorry to late reply. Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert So if we are in $\mathbb F_3$ or $\mathbb Z_4$ (ring of modulus $4$) and error is in $0/1$ it works? It does not work only when we are in $\mathbb F_{2^i}$ (char $2$) and error is in $0/1$ correct?

Comment: For $\mathbb{F}_3$ it may work; of course the details would need to be checked carefully. For $\mathbb{Z}_4$ there is the additional complication that the ultimate linear system would be over just a ring (not a field), but it seems like that could be overcome.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert "..it seems like that could be overcome".. what makes you think so? Any references you may know on this?